# need to properly map data in my success function

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a success function in my ajax call. The issue I am facing is I need to map the data that gets returned. Outside of this function it maps correctly, but not within. Any help

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "https://example.com",
  type: 'Get',
  headers: {
    accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
  },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    vm.items = data;
    data.Modules.map(function(module) {
      if (module.Topics.length) {
        var url, text
        if (module.Topics[1]) {
          url = module.Topics[1].Url
          text = module.Topics[1].Title
        } else {
          url = module.Topics[0].Url
          text = module.Topics[0].Title
        }
      }
      return {
        url,
        text
      }
    })
  },
})
}
},
```

Comment: You have several extra `}` at the end.

Comment: You're not assigning the result of `map()` to anything. So what's the point of it?

Comment: How is it not mapping correctly? What are you expecting it to do? You're just creating an array of objects, but not doing anything with it.

Comment: guess I am asking how do i assign the returned items to the map?

Comment: `newVariable = data.Modules.map(...`